# linked FrameWork and library grays out after pushing to git

Tags: swift, xcode, git, repository, xcode8

I have pc running Mac Sierra and Xcode 8.3 which I can't upgrade it.

there is lap top which is upgrade it to high Sierra and Xcode 9

I develop an app and push it on Git then laptop pulls it and make build for appStore.

after clone and pull Xcode not detecting libraries.

I do following :

clean build  delete derived data  clean again   add libraries

- pod install pod update

  restart xcode
- delete whole cocoa-touch and install again delete whole pod file and
  install again

important tip is it is running on simulator but can't archive it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove libraries and change build setting framework search path to $(PROJECT_DIR)

clean build .with no library added